# Replace quoted-printable newlines (=\n) with sed after the first occurence of specific word

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace every quoted-printable newline, but only after the first occurence of a specific word.

Example:

```
blabla=
test

--69c1683a3ee16ef7cf16edd700694a2f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Manuel Lemos' MIME E-mail composing and sending PHP class: H=
TML message</title>
<style type=3D"text/css"><!--
body { color: black ; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; backgroun=
d-color: #A3C5CC }
A:link, A:visited, A:active { text-decoration: underline }
--></style>
</head>
<body>
<table background=3D"cid:4c837ed463ad29c820668e835a270e8a.gif" width=3D"100=
%">
<tr>
<td>
<center><h1>Testing Manuel Lemos' MIME E-mail composing and sending PHP cla=
ss: HTML message</h1></center>
<hr>
<P>Hello Manuel,<br><br>
This message is just to let you know that the <a href=3D"http://www.phpclas=
ses.org/mimemessage">MIME E-mail message composing and sending PHP class</a=
> is working as expected.<br><br>
<center><h2>Here is an image embedded in a message as a separate part:</h2>=
</center>
<center><img src=3D"cid:ae0357e57f04b8347f7621662cb63855.gif"></center>Than=
k you,<br>
mlemos</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
--69c1683a3ee16ef7cf16edd700694a2f--
```

So far I am using this sed command:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;$s/=\n//g'
```

Result:

```
blablatest

--69c1683a3ee16ef7cf16edd700694a2f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Manuel Lemos' MIME E-mail composing and sending PHP class: HTML message</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
body { color: black ; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; background-color: #A3C5CC }
A:link, A:visited, A:active { text-decoration: underline }
--></style>
</head>
<body>
<table background="cid:4c837ed463ad29c820668e835a270e8a.gif" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<center><h1>Testing Manuel Lemos' MIME E-mail composing and sending PHP class: HTML message</h1></center>
<hr>
<P>Hello Manuel,<br><br>
This message is just to let you know that the <a href="http://www.phpclasses.org/mimemessage">MIME E-mail message composing and sending PHP class</a> is working as expected.<br><br>
<center><h2>Here is an image embedded in a message as a separate part:</h2></center>
<center><img src="cid:ae0357e57f04b8347f7621662cb63855.gif"></center>Thank you,<br>
mlemos</p>
```

The problem is, that

```
blabla=
test
```

also turns into

```
blablatest
```

So I want the sed command only to execute after the first occurence of "html".
I have tried:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;/html/,$s/=\n//g'
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `/<html>/` address before the commands :

```
sed '/<html>/{:a;N;$!ba;$s/=\n//g}' file
```